Check if variable satisfies type definition in string
Is there a way to test if a $var satisfies a type defined in a string other than this:
function test_type(mixed $value, string $type): bool 
{
    try { 
          eval('(fn('.$type.' $a)=>true)($value);'); 
          return true;  
    }  
    catch (Throwable  $e) { 
          return false; 
    }
}
test_type(null,  "int") ; // returns false. 
test_type(null,  "?int") ; // return true. 
test_type("hello, world", "bool") ; // returns true. I want it to return false
test_type(new DateTime, "DateTimeInterface") ; // return true. 
test_type(new DateTime, "null|int|DateTime|DateTimeImmutable") ; // return true

There are two major problems with this approach that do not need further explanation:

eval
automatic type conversion (as in test_type("hello, world", "bool") => true )

Is there a way to avoid these problems? I've Googled a lot but haven't found anything up to now.

For who is wondering: it's for a property hook simulator until; PHP 8.4 comes out so I can already implement the logic without much rewriting later.

I mean, I haven't wrote much more tests but I achieved your expected output by just mixing gettype and instanceof. You can see it over on 3v4l.org and hopefully it helps. Might need to extend it slightly..

Thanks for your code. I'm impressed by how quick you did that. A lot of types are missing but easily added. However it doesn't work for echo (int) test_type(0,  "int|bool");Also intersection type are not supported. You put me on the right path though, I am rewriting your code as we speak.

I honestly wonder why you'd want to write such code. BTW, concerning the automatic type conversions, there's declare(strict_types=1) which any new sourcefile should include.

Thanks! Sometimes I forget about the most obvious of things....
BTW I wrote why in the first comment.

@Jaquarh convinced me it was way easier than I thought it would be by just testing all the types and unions and intersections. His version was the basis for this solution. Thanks, Jaquarh!
function test_type(mixed $value, string $type): bool
{   if ( $type == 'mixed' ) return true;
    $foundType =  strtolower(gettype($value)); 
    $foundType = ['boolean'=>'bool', 'integer'=>'int', 'double'=>'float'][$foundType] ?? $foundType;
    
    $type = str_replace('?', 'null|', $type);
    $typesUnion = explode('|', $type);
    $typesIntersection = explode('&', $type);
    if ( count($typesIntersection)>1) {
        if (  ! is_object($value) ) return false;
        foreach($typesIntersection as $subtype) {
            if ( ! ($value instanceof $subtype)) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    foreach($typesUnion as $subtype) {
        if(match(strtolower($subtype)) {
             $foundType => true,
             'false'    => $value === false,
             'true'     => $value === true,
             'callable' => is_callable($value),
             default    => is_object($value) &&  $value instanceof $subtype
            }) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

enum hello { case world; case earth; case mars; };

echo (int) test_type(false,  "int|bool");                                   // 1
echo (int) test_type(null,  "?int");                                        // 1
echo (int) test_type(null,  "int|string");                                  // 0
echo (int) test_type("hello, world", "?bool");                              // 0
echo (int) test_type(hello::world, "hello");                                // 1
echo (int) test_type(false, "DateTimeInterface|false");                     // 1
echo (int) test_type(true, "DateTimeInterface|false");                      // 0
echo (int) test_type(new DateTime, "DateTimeInterface|false");              // 1
echo (int) test_type(new DateTime, "null|int|DateTime|DateTimeImmutable");  // 1
echo (int) test_type(new DateTime, "DateTime&DateTimeInterface");           // 1
echo (int) test_type([1,2,3,4], "Array");                                   // 1
echo (int) test_type(fn($x) => $x+1, "callable");                           // 1
echo (int) test_type($x = fopen('php://output', 'w'), "object|resource");   // 1

https://onlinephp.io/c/59f73

Glad it helped, consider marking your answer as the accepted answer once SO allows you too to help future viewers :) Best of luck with your project!
